# Custom message for "Could not found main class"

Tags: advanced-installer

I am using Advanced installer and its working very good for me till now, some times because of any issue my exe don't find the main class and it gives an alert message i-e "Could not find the main class abc/test/MyClass" i like to make this message custom for user as some users are not use to "with programmatic terms" or "this type of messages" so we like to add a custom message for that, kindly tell how can we...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Googled](https://www.google.com.pk/) it but found that [Advanced installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=22086) does not have any option for this till now